# Laravel solo me da el error 500 para todo

Tags: laravel

Desde hace unos días sin razón alguna mi proyecto en Laravel para mostrarme cualquier error solo muestra el error 500 y no me especifica ni da detalles del error. Les ha pasado? Alguna sugerencia? Mi proyecto esta corriendo en local.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para ver el error que obtienes debes cambiar la variable  APP_DEBUG de tu archivo .env a TRUE.

Comment: @BPolanco, los errores 500 son de servidor, revisa cuales se grabaron en el log de errores de Laravel y por favor agrégalos a tu pregunta

Comment: El archivo esta en **`storage/logs/laravel.log`**

Comment: Muchas gracias @L.Flor y a todos los demás por sus comentarios. Efectivamente tenia APP_DEBUG en True.

Comment: @BPolanco y entonces la pregunta cuál es?

Comment: @BetaM mi duda era por que todos los errores eran 500.